# Sprites and Movements with Arrows keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I have been working on making a sprite for a game. My goal is to make my picture of a square to move. However I am facing difficulties in actually moving the square. Any help for as to what is wrong with the key event part of my code would be very much so appreciated.

```
import pygame
import sys
import time
from time import sleep
import random
from pygame.locals import *


image1 = pygame.image.load('square.png')



class sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):

        self.image = pygame.image.load('square.png')
        self.image = self.image.convert_alpha()
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = 100
        self.y = 100
        self.dx=50
        self.dy=50

    def update(self):
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    self.x -= self.dx
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    self.x += self.dx
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.x -= self.dx
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.x += self.dx
        self.rect.center=(self.x,self.y)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    sprite.dy = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    sprite.dx = 0
    def background(self, surface):
        self.image2 = pygame.image.load(white.png)
        screen.blit(self.image2, (0,0))

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1250, 500))
screen.fill((255,255,255))

my_sprite=sprite()

while True:


    pygame.init()
    pygame.event.get()
    pygame.event.pump
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           pygame.quit()

    my_sprite.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't put `pygame.init()` in your loop.

I have a feeling that your problem is because in your `update()` method of the `sprite`, `event` is not even defined. Add the line `for event in pygame.event.get():` at the start of the method and indent the rest under it.

```
def update(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        ... # Rest of the method
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I applied your changes however the square still remains unresponsive when I press down my arrow keys.